# Does touchpad indicator work in Ubuntu 15.04?

Tags: touchpad

I have just tried to install touchpad indicator in Ubuntu 15.04 with these instructions:

> **Touchpad indicator** is developed by atareao team, available in the PPA for Ubuntu 14.04, Ubuntu 13.10, Ubuntu 12.04. To install it, press Ctrl+Alt+T on keyboard to open terminal. When it opens, run the commands below one by one:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/atareao 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install touchpad-indicator
```

I get an error message after launching it....the app closed unexpectedly. Why is that? It is no longer supported?

Does anyone know of a working alternative in 15.04?

Comment: I'm currently evaluating whether or not to install touchpad-indicator. I may not run into problems immediately (using 14.04-based Mint), but this may be interesting in the future. *Have you tried again? Did you find a replacement?*

Comment: It works fine in 14.04. Seems to be working fine in 16.04 too.

Answer (score 0):

This has been solved in Ubuntu 16.04. The configuration file was not being created so you need to created yourself. To make it work in 15.04, run:

```
mkdir ~/.config/touchpad-indicator
touch ~/.config/touchpad-indicator/touchpad-indicator.conf
echo '{}' > ~/.config/touchpad-indicator/touchpad-indicator.conf
```

You can find that bug [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/touchpad-indicator/+bug/1476064). It does not show as solved, because the person behind that program does not seem to use Launchpad very much. It seems he prefers his [own website](https://www.atareao.es/).